# How to set up a Drupal 7 forum

Tags: 7, nodes

I have installed the core Forum module in Drupal 7.  When I go to:

```
http://www.mysite.com/?q=forum
```

The forum list is displayed, however the links that allow me to post are not being displayed.

I'm surprised that I haven't been able to find a tutorial on the net on how to set up a Drupal 7 forum.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your theme is probably not presenting the new action links in D7. In a default install of D7 and forum (using Bartik theme) I can see them. See http://definitivedrupal.org/suggestions/action-links for an explanation.

Comment: You're probably right. But I took the forums.tpl.php template from the Forum module directory and I have not modified it.  How do I make Drupal display the $action_links?

Comment: i personally use the omaga tools module http://drupal.org/project/omega_tools which expses these elements as block, so I can easily place them where i need. (you can also use http://drupal.org/project/blockify to get the blocks)